# Burninate [syllable]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[syllable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syllable) seems pretty useless; I can't imagine anyone being much of an expert in "syllable" programming, for example. But I haven't been around long enough to be comfortable using the machete on fully 23 questions, so is this the good idea I think it is?

Comment: Tough to say.  There are some quality questions there that would benefit from having this tag around.

Comment: @Makoto: can you give some examples of which ones you think are good, maybe in an answer?

Comment: Probably not answer-worthy (nor would I recommend answering for me right now; it's really late and I'm quite sleepy) - I'd take a look at [the questions above 4 total score](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsyllable%5D+is%3Aquestion+score%3A4..).  Ignore that PHP question, it's...asking for a library.  The others seem to be earnest discussions about natural language processing.

Comment: Fair enough. Not sure it adds much beyond [nlp], but perhaps it does.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [PC operating system called Syllable](http://web.syllable.org/pages/index.html), a variant of AtheOS. So saying one can't be an expert in [syllable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syllable) is like saying one can't be an expert in [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows). If we retag natural language processing questions in [syllable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syllable) to [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp), we can reserve [syllable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syllable) for the Syllable operating system

Comment: None of the questions currently tagged [tag:syllable] have anything to do with the OS, so I'm happy retagging and letting the chips fall where they may. If we actually need a tag for the OS, it can be recreated if necessary.